# Rear brake pads and rotors on a Chev Malibu

Tags: chevrolet

I had new rear brake pads and rotors installed at an automotive shop in May of 2016 and already need new pads and rotors is what I'm being told.  When I make hard turns, I hear what sounds like a repetitive clicking sound.  I've only driven about 20,000 Kilometers in the last 3 years and I never abuse the brakes with hard stops etc.  How can this be?  Could it be that they put in the cheapest pads and rotors?  What should I be asking for this time around?  Thank you.

Comment: The clicking sound on hard turns is more likely a CV joint than a rear brake issue.  Does it seem more pronounced in one turn direction?

Comment: Is this the front wheel drive version or rear?

Comment: This sounds unlikely, I'd get a second opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The clicking only happens on right turns and my car is front wheel drive.  I did get a second opinion as lately (or maybe I never notice it before cause it wasn't pronounced), there's a noise that sounds like an airplane engine when I drive over 50 km/hr.  I'm now told the culprit is a front left wheel bearing. He'll hoist the car and listen with a stethoscope to confirm.  Wish I knew which is the bad one cause he actually replaced the F/R bearing last year..wonder if it's the same one.  Hope he'll tell me if it is but I'll never know I guess.